# EditText já preenchido após o login do usuário utilizando firebase

Tags: android, firebase, edittext

Olá!

Estou com uma dúvida de um processo que não estou conseguindo fazer.
Tenho a seguinte tela, e queria que o EditText usuário já fique preenchido com o nome do usuário ou o e-mail do usuário. Sou novo na área de programação mobile, e tentei fazer isso com sharedpreferences, mas, não consegui montar o código.

Segue a tela da activity e do banco firebase que estou utilizando.
[image: Activity - campo usuário]
Segue o código que fiz da activity até aqui.
public class MensagemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText edtNome, edtMensagem;
Button btnEnviarMensagem;
Mensagem mensagem;

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensagem);

    edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
    edtMensagem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMensagem);
    btnEnviarMensagem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarMensagem);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    btnEnviarMensagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mensagem = new Mensagem();
            mensagem.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());
            mensagem.setMensagem(edtMensagem.getText().toString());

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            databaseReference.child("mensagens").push().setValue(firebaseDatabase, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    //Problem with saving the data
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MensagemActivity.this, "Erro ao criar ocorrência / erro ao inserir dados!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        //Data uploaded successfully on the server
                        databaseReference.child("nome").setValue(edtNome.getText().toString());
                        databaseReference.child("texto").setValue(edtMensagem.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MensagemActivity.this, "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        retornaTela();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

[image: Banco com os dados de mensagem e usuario]
Se alguém puder me ajudar por gentileza, fico grato.
Abraços.

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde !
Nesse caso você vai precisar de um ValueEventListener para recuperar as informações desse usuário no sistema, você precisará criar uma instancia apontando para por exemplo databaseReference.getinstance().child("usuario").child("condominio").(nesse caso como vc usou o metodo push eu nao sei como recuperar esse valor rsrs, mas seria o push"KtDIZ...").child("nome");
Assim vc terá uma referencia para esse nó e depois pode acessa-lo pelo eentlistener... Segue exemplo de um código que eu fiz hj que nesse caso retorna todos os dados do usuario cadastrado no firebase:

```
/********************INICIO DA CAPTURA DE DADOS DO USUARIO ****************************/
    SharedPreferencesUser preferencesUser = new SharedPreferencesUser(getActivity());
    idUsuario = preferencesUser.getIdentificador();

    firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getDataBase()
            .child("USUARIOS")
            .child(idUsuario);

    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null){
                Usuarios usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuarios.class);

                //SETANDO OS VALORES NA CLASSE MODEL
                nome.setText(usuario.getNome());
                email.setText(usuario.getEmail());
                nasc.setText(usuario.getNascimento());
                prof.setText(usuario.getProfissao());
                pais.setText(usuario.getPais());
                estado.setText(usuario.getEstado());
                cid.setText(usuario.getCidade());
                tel.setText(usuario.getTelefone());
                escolaridade.setText(usuario.getEscolaridade());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    firebase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    /**********************FIM DA CAPTURA DE DADOS DO USUARIO *****************************/
```

Desse jeito eu tenho salvo no sharedpreferences o ID do usuario, então passando ele na referenciaFirebase que eu chamei de firebase eu consigo acessar todos os nós a partir daí e seta-los nos TextViews ou EditText, além disso estou usando a classe usuário model para mediar os dados, o segredo nesse caso é o dataSnapshot, ele é quem trás os dados do minha referencia.
Aconselho a pesquisar sobre valueEventListener.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br.
Esse é a classe responsavel por armazenar o id do meu usuario, nesse caso também uso o bas para gerar um Id criptografado, ao fazer login com o usuario eu salvo seus Id na classe SharedPreferenceUser com o seguinte comando: `

```
                        //SALVANDO OS DADOS NO SHARED PREFERENCES
                        SharedPreferencesUser preferencesUser = new SharedPreferencesUser(LoginActivity.this);
                        preferencesUser.salvarUsuarioPreferences(identificador, gNome);
```

Onde gnome é a variavel que recebe o nome do usuario e o identificador é o id dele,  então quando eu faço o login eu salvo esses dados para poder recupera-los nas demias activities com a chamada anterior.

```
public class SharedPreferencesUser {

//ATRIBUTOS
private Context contexto;
private SharedPreferences preferencias;
private final String NOME_ARQUIVO = "STUDYNG.PREFERENCES";
private final int MODE = 0;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private final String CHAVE_IDENTIFICADOR = "identificador";
private final String CHAVE_NOME = "nomeUsuario";

public SharedPreferencesUser(Context contextoParametro){
    contexto = contextoParametro;
    preferencias = contexto.getSharedPreferences(NOME_ARQUIVO, MODE);
    editor = preferencias.edit();
}

//SALVANDO E RECUPERANDO USUARIOS
public void salvarUsuarioPreferences(String ident, String nome){
    editor.putString(CHAVE_IDENTIFICADOR, ident);
    editor.putString(CHAVE_NOME, nome);
    editor.commit();
}

//RECUPERANDO
public String getIdentificador(){
    return preferencias.getString(CHAVE_IDENTIFICADOR, null);
}

public String getUsuarioNome(){
    return preferencias.getString(CHAVE_NOME, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Certo Eduardo, obrigado pela resposta. 

Mas, esse seu código, é inserido no on create? No caso se eu o utilizasse como base, eu o incluiria em que lugar no meu postado acima (claro que com as alterações necessárias)?

Comment: Isso, ele é criado no metodo oncreate, o firebase.addEventListener é o responsavel por ativa-lo, mas você pode inserir o firebase.addEventListener no metodo on Start, assim toda vez que a activity for startada ela chamará o EventoOuvinte, também aconselho a sobrescrever o metodo onStop e nele inserir o seguinte(para economia de recursos): firebase.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);

Comment: Eduardo, esse SharedPreferencesUser, você criou como? Pois não consegui implementar o sharedpreference com esses mesmos parâmetros que você setou.